# The number of functions $f: {\cal P}_n \to \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$ such that $f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A), f(B)\}$ (Putnam 1993)

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

Let ${\cal P}_n$ be the set of subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots,
n\}$. Let $c(n, m)$ be the number of functions $f: {\cal P}_n \to \{1, 2,
\dots, m\}$ such that $f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A), f(B)\}$. Prove that
$c(n, m) = \sum_{j=1}^m j^n.$ 
(Putnam 1993 A-3)

My question is how should I interpret the functions we are looking for? Can someone give me an example?
$f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A), f(B)\}$

Comment: Just a comment.  Keep in mind that $ A \cap B \in \cal P_{n} $.  There are three cases $ A \cap B = A, A \cap B = B $ or $ A \cap B = C $ where $C \subset A, C \subset B. $

Comment: I'm really a beginner and don't know how such a function looks like. For example $n = 5$ and $f(\{1,2,3\}) = \min\{f(A),f(B)\}$, but what are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The key point is that the value of $f(A\cap B)$ is determined by the values of $f(A)$ and $f(B)$, so look for a collection of sets that give all others by intersections.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, we could take $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,5\}$. Then $$f(\{1,2,3\})=\min\{f(\{1,2,3,4\}),f(\{1,2,3,5\})$$The same holds for all other pairs of sets containing $\{1,2,3\}$. I'll call a function $f$ **admissible** if
$$f(A\cap B)=\min\{f(A), f(B)\}$$
holds for all subset $A,B$ of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. We will use the shorthand $[n]=\{1,\cdots,n\}$.

On these sorts of problems, it helps to start with a simple case. When $m=1$, the problems asks us to prove that there is exactly 1 admissible function. Do you see why this is?

**Warning: Stop reading here if you don't want spoilers.**

For motivation, consider the case $m=2$ (technically, we don't need to handle this case separately since it's subsumed by the inductive argument). We want to show that there are $2^n+1$ admissible functions. There are two possibilities; either $f\equiv 1$, or else $f$ attains the value 2.

*Claim:* There are $2^n$ admissible functions $f\colon P([n])\to [2]$ such that $\max f=2$.

*Proof:* We will exhibit a bijection between such functions $f$ and subsets $E_f\subset [n]$.

First, suppose we're given a subset $E\subset [n]$. Define the corresponding $f$ by setting $f(A)=2$ if $A\supset E$, and $f(A)=1$ otherwise (in particular, $f(E)=2$). This function is admissible since if $A,B\supset E$, then also $A\cap B\supset E$.

Now suppose we're given an admissible function $f$. Let $E_f$ be the minimal subset of $[n]$ for which $f(E_f)=2$. Note that the existence of such a set relies on the admissibility hypothesis, as well as $f\not\equiv 1$. Hence we've constructed the desired bijection. $\square$

The same argument generalizes to the following:

*Claim:* There are $m^n$ admissible functions $f\colon P([n])\to [m]$ such that $\max f=m$.

*Proof:* We will exhibit a slightly more involved bijection between such functions $f$ and chains of subsets.

Given an admissible function $f$, form the sequence of subsets $\{E_f^1,\cdots, E_f^n\}$ as follows. For $i\in [n]$, $E_f^i$ is the minimal subset that satisfies $f(E_f^i)=i$. Notice that $E_f^1\subset E_f^2\subset \cdots\subset E_f^n$. Similarly, if we're given an increasing chain $A_1\subset \cdots \subset A_n$, construct an admissible function $f$ by setting $f(B)$ to be the minimal index $i$ such that $A_i\subset B$. Thus we have a bijection between our set of functions under consideration, and the set of chains of subsets of height $n$. There are $m^n$ such chains (since the chains are in bijection with functions $g\colon [n]\to [m]$). $\square$

We've basically solved the problem now. Indeed, we group together the set of admissible functions $f\colon P([n])\to [m]$ by $\max f$. By the previous claim, there are $j^n$ functions in the group $\max f=j$. Hence there are $\sum_{j=1}^m j^n$ functions in total.

Answer (score 2):

For notational ease, let $N = \{1,\ldots,n\}$, $N_i = [n]\setminus\{i\}$, and $M = \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

First, assume that $f : \mathcal{P}_n \to M$ and that $f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A),f(B)\}$.

Choose $i \in N$ and $j \in M$. It is certain that $f(N) \in M$, so suppose $f(N) = j$. Then $f(N \cap N_i) = f(N_i) = \min\{f(N),f(N_i)\}$. It follows that for all $i$, $f(N_i) \le f(N) = j$.

As an intermediate step, I will prove via induction that when we specify $f(N) = j$ for some $j \in M$ and $f(N_i)$ for all $i \in N$, $f$ has been fully specified and is well-defined. Assume that $f(S) = \min_{i \not\in S}\{f(N_i)\}$ for subsets $S \subset N$ where $m \le |S| \le n-1$. Now, consider subsets $S \in N$ where $|S| = m-1$. Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $N$ such that $|A|,|B| \ge m$ and $A \cap B = S$.

Note that the condition $f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A),f(B)\}$ is enough to guarantee that the image of $S$ under $f$ is defined at all, because we can always find at least two sets $A,B$ with the above requirements such that $A \cap B = S$. For instance, take $a,b \in N$ such that $a,b \not\in S, a \ne b$; then let $A = S \cup \{a\}$ and $B = S \cup \{B\}$. Then $A \ne B$ and $|A|,|B| \ge m$ and $A \cap B = S$, and since $|S| < n-1$ it is indeed possible to choose two distinct numbers $a,b$ that are in $N$ but not in $S$.

Then
$$f(S) = f(A \cap B) = \min\{f(A),f(B)\} = \min\{\min_{i \not\in A}\{f(N_i)\},\min_{i \not\in B}\{f(N_i)\}\}.$$
Observe that $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c = S^c$, so in fact
$$f(S) = \min{i \not\in S}\{f(N_i)\}.$$
That is, given any choice of subsets $A,B$ of $N$ where both sets are larger than $S$ and $S = A \cap B$, $f(A \cap B) = f(S)$ is the same, so it is not ill-defined. Alternatively, we have the case where either $A$ or $B$ is the same size as $S$. Suppose without loss of generality that, in this situation, $|A| = |S|$. Then $A = S$, and along similar lines we have
$$f(S) = f(A \cap B) = f(S \cap B) = \min\{f(S),f(B)\} = \min\{\min_{i \not\in S}\{f(N_i)\},\min_{i \not\in B}\{f(N_i)\}\} = \min_{i \not\in S} \{f(N_i)\}.$$
As such, the above conclusion holds for any decomposition of $S$ into the intersection of two sets of equal or greater cardinality. To complete the induction, take $m = n-1$ as the base case. Observe that any subset of $N$ with cardinality $n-1$ is one of the sets $N_i$. Then
$$f(S) = f(N_i) = \min_{i \not\in S}\{f(N_i)\},$$
which follows almost tautologically. The intermediate step is finished, and we have demonstrated that when $f(N)$ and $f(N_i)$ are defined, $f$ is well-defined when acting on any other subset of $N$.

It follows that the number of functions $f$ which the initial assumptions given $f(N) = j$ is equal to the number of ways to assign $f(N_i)$ to some element of $M$ for every $i \in N$ such that $f(N_i) \le j$. That is to say, it is equal to the number of functions from $N$ to $\{1,\ldots,j\}$, which is clearly $j^m$. Then to count every single possible function, we sum over $j$, *i.e.*,
$$c(n,m) = \sum_{j=1}^m j^n.$$